# Facebook How Manually Build a Login Flow (PHP) error "your redirect_uri isn't identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I know people asked about this question, but their answer-advice don't help me

I try get access_toke along this path:

https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=$appID&redirect_uri=$appURI&client_secret=$appKey&code=$code

But I catch "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"

I use the same $appURI which use when build the link to auth through facebook

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow?locale=ru_RUhttps%3A%2F%2Fenglishrules.netlify.app)

Thank you in advance

Comment: I found where the problem was ... It's banal and funny and offensive at the same time


I have not done url encoding

Answer (score 0):

you have used different redirect_uri in your facebook app settings and Oauth API code. thats why you got this error.parameter of redirect_uri graph api must match with facebook app redirect_url.

Comment: I use the same uri in facebook App(login) or or are you not talking about that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the URL of the URI, which is specified in the facebook login(product)

$facebookURI = urlencode('YourSite);